# Can't debug native c++ code for Android in Eclipse on Windows

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk

Does anyone know how to debug a Native Android Application from Eclipse on Windows? It looks like Linux users don't experience any problems with it.

The main goal is to start debug process from Eclipse (without any console manipulations after each run).

I went through a lot of tutorials but none of them made me able to break execution on set breakpoints in c++ code (I tried at least 10 of them).

I have no CR LF problem in gdb.setup, I have C++ code compiled with `ndk-build -j8 NDK_DEBUG=1` Eclipse. All my breakpoints are set as a reaction on user click, so gdb should be already connected. When I click "Debug As Native Android Application", I get the following output:

```
    warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 72 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
    Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
    Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
    warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
    GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
    that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
    or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
    [New Thread 3239]
    [New Thread 3241]
    [New Thread 3242]
    [New Thread 3243]
    [New Thread 3244]
    [New Thread 3245]
    [New Thread 3246]
    [New Thread 3247]
    [New Thread 3248]
    The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
    No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
    No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: Are you using MinGW? Do you have gdb installed?

Comment: No, I use ndk-build script from NDK to compile native code. And I suppose Eclipse use ADT plugin to find correct path to gdb which is also provided by NDK.

Comment: Ah good, have you set the path to NDK? Preferences->Android->NDK

Comment: Yes, of course. My c++ code is built from Eclipse with simple ndk-build command in C++ Build section of project properties.

Comment: Well, maybe you can try [this](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/). Good luck ;)